# ReactJS : How to use ReactMarkDown?

Tags: reactjs

Hey I'm trying to figure out how to use ReactMarkDown.

Any idea how to use this ?

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

const About = () => {

const input = `### There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here'`
 
return (
  <div>
    <ReactMarkdown source={input}/> // Wont display :'(
  </div>
);
};

export default About;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to read the documentation of library, you can find in the [npm page](https://npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) or in [github project](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown).
Essentially you can do in two way.

**First pass props to component:**

```
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

const About = () => {
  const input = `### There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here'`;

  return <div>
      <ReactMarkdown children={input} />
    </div>

};
```

**Second insert markdown text inside the component**

```
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

const About = () => {
  const input = `### There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here'`;

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMarkdown>{input}</ReactMarkdown>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! Its working perfectly now :)